# creating csv file to upload to moodle

Tags: php, csv, laravel, moodle

Edit: I have tried changing the PHP_EOL to "\n",
tried creating the file on the server using fputcsv and then download it to the user
and tried to create my csv file using this approach:

```
        $callback = function() use ($grades)
    {
        $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $csv_headers = "Identifier,Email addres,Status,Grade,Scale,Grade can be changed,Last modified (submission),Last modified (grade),Feedback comments";
        fputcsv($FH,explode(',',$csv_headers));

        foreach ($grades as $grade) {
            $moodle_stud_id = $grade->moodle_stud_id;
            $points = $grade->grade;
            $csv_line = "Participant ".$moodle_stud_id.",,,".$points.",,Yes,,,,";
            fputcsv($FH,explode(',',$csv_line));
        }
        fclose($FH);
    };
return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

all giving back the same result, the file wont be accepted in Moodle unless I open it on my computer and save it, any ideas?

end of edit

I'm using a web application with laravel framework to create a csv file which a user can download, and use that cav file to upload data to another system - to be specific it's a csv file containing students grades to be uploaded into moodle.

If i download the file from my system. and try to upload it to moodle, the moodle doesnt recognize the grades, and says there are no grades to update

But. if i download the file from my system, open it save it and close it, and then trying to upload to moodle - then everything works great

any ideas?
this is the way I'm creating the csv file:

```
  $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="grades.csv"',
    );
    $output = implode(",", array('Identifier', 'Email address', 'Status','Grade','Scale','Grade can be changed','Last modified (submission)','Last modified (grade)','Feedback comments'));
    $output .= PHP_EOL;
foreach ($grades as $grade) {
    $output .= implode(",", array("Participant ".$moodle_stud_id,'','',$grade,'','Yes','','','','')); // append each row
    $output .= PHP_EOL;
}
return Response::make($output, 200, $headers);
```

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is the end of line characters. whatever you are opening and saving it with might be converting `\n` to `\r\n` or something similar. just a guess.

Comment: do u mean the PHP_EOL?

Comment: Just a thought but the values might need to be enclosed in quotes. Maybe try `$output = '"' . implode('","', array(...)) . '"';` also set the encoding to utf8 `'Content-Encoding' => 'UTF-8';`

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved by opening the file using notepad i noticed that the file i created had an extra colum at the end of each row beside from the headers row, which was deleted when opening and saving the file

guess its sort of a type error, should i delete the question?